# How to point gradle to local dependency that can have different paths?

Tags: java, gradle

To make it more clear, i have a code in my jar that when run it downloads needed jars to function correctly and it stored them in **/wherever/jar/is/located/newFolder/libs/**. Now what i have done is added those dependencies that are manually downloaded as **compileOnly** in my gradle but i dont know how to point gradle to location where the downloaded libs are since it can be different path on each machine that is run.

The dependency in question is io.sentry that i download to libs when the jar runs but how to tell my jar where to find classes if they are in libs folder as i previously stated.

```
dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    compileOnly 'org.jetbrains:annotations:15.0'
    compileOnly 'io.sentry:sentry:1.7.30'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`org.jetbrains:annotations` and `io.sentry:sentry` are available publicly online. There's no need to download the artifacts manually. You can simply do:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    compileOnly 'org.jetbrains:annotations:15.0'
    compileOnly 'io.sentry:sentry:1.7.30'
}
```

But if for some reason you must import the artifacts locally, then you can do something like:

```
repositories {
   flatDir {
       dirs '/wherever/jar/is/located/newFolder/libs/'
   }
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    compileOnly 'org.jetbrains:annotations:15.0'
    compileOnly 'io.sentry:sentry:1.7.30'
}
```

Or include them one by one:

```
dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    compileOnly files('/wherever/jar/is/located/newFolder/libs/libs/jetbrains.jar')
    compileOnly files('/wherever/jar/is/located/newFolder/libs/libs/sentry.jar'
}
```